# How to unpublish content that is under moderation

Tags: nodes, 8

I am using the [Content Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_moderation) module in Drupal 8.2 and I have noticed there is no way to re-unpublish a node once it has been moderated into a published state. I'm able to create a new draft of the content and moderate that through to published state but I can't find a way to actually unpublish the node.

There is a [bug issue on DO](https://www.drupal.org/node/2825579) that seems related, but looking at the patch it only adds a message informing you that you can't unpublish content directly once under moderation. Which makes sense as having content moderation enabled means you are handing over control of publish/unpublish to that module. But that leaves the question of how to actually unpublish a node that is under moderation?

I understand this module is currently experimental but am fairly sure I am missing something here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable the default revision for all the states. If there is any transition in any state from publish to draft or any state.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, i re-instated the archived state which i had deleted and set the default revision flag and everything is now as expected.

Comment: This helped me figure out the problem.  Edit each of your custom workflow states and select the Default revision.  This allows content to go back to being unpublished.  Hope this helps someone who is battling this slightly confusing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although Sumit Madan solution explains what is the reason and how you can have unpublished/published content with moderation state still you are not able to update bulky.

This is a solution I found for my cause, it may be helpful for others,

first, install https://www.drupal.org/project/moderated_content_bulk_publish module.

second, if you don't have  `archived` state, create it. you can label it to whatever you want but machine name should be `archived` ( because moderated_content_bulk_publish acts based on that).

then go to your `admin/content` page and  bulky **Publish/unpublish current revision**.

That's it. there will be no **"One or more entities were skipped as they are under moderation and may not be directly published or unpublished"** warning anymore

Answer (score 0):

I invit you to have a look to my comment (link below) on the default behaviour of this module  "Workflow" and how you can create a "Draft unpublish" state to unpublish your content after it has been published.

[Workflow: how unpublish a published content by changing the state to "Draft"](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3276089#comment-14737505)